# Brahmacharya and sleeplessness

Tags: brahmacharya, sleep

Namasthe,
I am practicing Brahmacharya for 3 months. I have lost my appetite, and sleep. Will it last for ever?

Comment: In case you are having sleep problems for more than a month. It is seriously recommended to seek help from a qualified medical professional as sleep disorder once triggered may last a lifetime and can cause disability throughout life. Be it any discipline, yoga, lifestyle, etc. It is important to have a good firm preparation and then slowly move towards mastery rather than to injure the physical body out of ego. Have firm faith, a slow start, and then bit-by-bit improvement is recommended unless urgency. This is not a good place to seek medical help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Seeking medical help is out of the scope of this community.